# Question About Filled Julia and Julia Sets

Tags: complex-analysis, chaos-theory, complex-dynamics

Question: Let $Q_{c}(z) = z^{2} +c $ which $ c \in \mathbb{C}$ and suppose that $z_{0} \in K _{c}$ for the filled Julia Set, $K_{c}$ of $Q_{c}$. Suppose further that $z_{1} = Q_{c}(z_{0})$ and it belongs to the Julia Set, $J_{c}$ of $Q_{c}$. Also, assume that $Q_{c} (K_{c}) = K_{c}$. Show that $z_{0} \in J_{c}$

My Attempt:  Since $z_{0}$ is in the Filled Julia Set, Also, what I think is that $z_{1} = Q_{c} (z_{0})$ means is that $z_{1}$ is a attracting critical point. I guess the only way that $z_{0} \in J_{c}$ is only when $z_{0}$ is a repelling periodic point. Should I use Cauchy's Inequality?  I am not sure what else to think about this problem.

Can you give me some hints on this problem please?

Thank you very much for your help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, it's not completely clear what you mean by the Julia set $J_c$; there are several equivalent formulations. Given your notation, I would not be surprised if you're studying one of Bob Devaney's books that uses the following defintions:

- The *filled* Julia set $K_c$ of $Q_c(z)=z^2+c$ is the set of all complex points whose orbit under iteration of $Q_c$ is bounded.

Then,

- The Julia set $J_c$ of $Q_c$ is the boundary of the filled Julia set, i.e. the closure of $K_c$ minus its interior.

If, for example, $c=0$, then $Q_0(z)=z^2$.  It's not too hard to see that, if $|z|\leq1$, then the orbit of $z$ is bounded by $1$. (You can't square a number less than or equal to $1$ in absolute value and get a number whose absolute value is larger than $1$). On the other hand, if $|z|>1$, then $|z^2|>|z|$. If we keep squaring, we generate a sequence that diverges to $\infty$. So for this example, the filled Julia set is exactly the solid unit disk, i.e.
 $$K_c = \left\{z\in\mathbb C:|z|\leq1\right\}.$$
The Julia set is the boundary of the unit disk, namely the unit circle:
 $$J_c = \left\{z\in\mathbb C:|z|=1\right\}.$$

For large $c$ values (outside of the Mandelbrot set, in fact), $K_c$ has empty interior so that $J_c=K_c$. For values in the interior of the Mandelbrot set, though, it appear that the above example is typical.

---

Now, you are essentially trying to show that $J_c$ is *backward invariant*, i.e. if $z_0\in J_c$ whenever $Q_c(z_0)\in J_c$. (Your problem, as stated, actually assumes more than is necessary.)  An outline of an approach might look like so:

- Pick an open set $U$ containing $z_0$.  You need to find a point in $U$ whose orbit is bounded and another point in $U$ whose orbit is unbounded.  As $U$ is arbitrary, you could then conclude that $z_0$ is on the boundary of $K_c$.
- Consider the image of $U$ under $Q_c$, i.e. $Q_c(U)$. This is an open set by the [open mapping theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open_mapping_theorem_%28complex_analysis%29).
- Now, since $Q_c(U)$ is an open set intersecting the boundary of $K_c$, it contains a point $Q_c(z_1)$ whose orbit is bounded and another point $Q_c(z_2)$ whose orbit is unbounded, where $z_1,z_2\in U$.
- The, of course, we can can draw the same conclusions on $z_1$ and $z_2$, so we are done.

---

Again, there are other characterizations of $J_c$. Another common one is: The Julia set $J_c$ is the closure of the set of repelling, periodic points of $Q_c$. It's worth mentioning that a similar argument works for this characterization as well.  If $Q_c(z_0)\in J_c$, then every neighborhood of $Q_c(z_0)$ contains a repelling periodic point. Again using the open mapping theorem, every neighborhood of $z_0$ will contain a repelling periodic point.

Comment: Okay. Sorry I did not clarify about the Julia Set. The Julia Set I am studying is exactly what you described, which is the boundary of the unit disk. Now to your questions, if I have an open set, which I need to find two points which the orbit of one point is bounded and the orbit of the other is unbounded respectively, then the two points which are in $Q_{c} (U)$ is when $|Q_{c}(z')| < 1$ and when $|Q_{c}(z')| > 1$. To be honest, I am not sure what I think about the second question.  Well since $Q_{c} (z_{0}) \in J_{c}$, it means that the magnitude of $Q_{c} (z_{0})$ equals 1.

Comment: @Overachiever I completed the argument more explicitly, rather than just providing hints. To address your specific questions, it seems that you have one point of fundamental confusion. Your original question does *not* concern the boundary of the unit disk. That's just a specific case, namely when $c=0$; most Julia sets are much more complicated than this. So there's no reason to suppose that $|Q_c(z_0)|=1$ when $Q_c(z_0)\in J_c$. Rather, you should draw conclusions on points in a neighborhood of $z_0$ from assumptions involving corresponding points in a neighborhood of $Q_c(z_0)$.